# How do I send an AJAX request and receive the (data)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

How I have my ajax function

```
$(function() {
  $("form#new_user").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
      var dataString = $('#new_user').serialize();


     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/user',
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) { 
        $('#alertt').text(data);
        $('#alertt').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
      }
      });
      return false;
```

and then on the php side it was just do its thing and then `json_encode(whatever)` so that when it got to the success: it could put the data into a `<p>` like Blah was successful

My Form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
```

--

But now on Rails, I'm assuming the setup is the same, but data to point like `url: '/users'` but how do I set the message to be sent back on Rails so that I can can set the `<p>` text to `User Created` or something a long those lines. Hopefully I made sense thanks.

e.g.

```
def create
if user.save?
sendmessagebacksomethinglike('User Created')
end
end
```

How would I send a message back so that I can use it with (data)?

Comment: If you add `dataType: "json"` you can remove `data = JSON.parse(data)` and it will be backward compatible with oldie

Comment: i dont get your question

Comment: @beck03076 I added a bit to the bottom to maybe clarify it a bit more

Comment: @KevinB Can you see the edit I made to the bottom of the original post, how would I send the data back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across 2 things commonly.

:partial, :text

```
def create

    if user.save?

    render :text => "User Created!"

    end

end


$.ajax(
  success: function(data) {    
    $('#alertt').text(data);    
  }
  });
  return false;
```

Mostly, I would render a partial after setting few instance variables in the controller and get that partial and paint it on the HTML in JS using a div. Never mind this. **What you are looking for is a render :text**

This a model which I think that can help you,

**view**

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => "do", 
                     :action => "something"),
                     :id => 'do',:method => 'post'  do %>

<% end %>
```

**application.js**

```
$(function() {

     $("form#do").submit(function() {  

      var data = $('form#do').serialize();

       $.post('/do_something',data, function(result){

        $("#done").hide().html(result).fadeIn(3000);

        });        

       return false;

      });

});
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/do_something' => "do#something" #routing do_something to do controller, something action.
```

**do_controller.rb**

```
def something

  render :text => 'did something'

end
```

Comment: One quick question, how do I prevent my page from going to the next page on clicking submit? I edited my main post to show my jquery setup

Comment: $("#registeruser").click => $("form#new_user").click

Comment: Do I put that in my .js or my new.html.erb?

Comment: no no.. i was meaning...you should change this  $("#registeruser").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); to this line  $("form#new_user").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();

Comment: Hmm, I put `$("form#new_user").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
` like you said but clicking `Register` it still redirects me to the blank white page with the render text

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs      those 3 lines have to be there in your application.js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25983/discussion-between-xcritics-and-beck03076)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the JS,

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/user',
  data: dataString,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $('#alertt').text(data.message);
  }
});
```

and this for the controller action,

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params)
  if @item.save
    render json: { message: "Successfully created." }.to_json, status: 201
  end
end
```

Comment: How do I stop my page from going to the rendered page on submit?